# How can I show a picture to imageView

Tags: android, imageview

in my android app, I need show an image retrieved by internet, in a ImageView, thi is my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... thumbURLs) {
    System.out.println("getting image");
    try{
        URL thumbURL = new URL(thumbURLs[0]);
        System.out.println("looking picture "+ thumbURLs[0]);
        URLConnection thumbConn = thumbURL.openConnection(); 
        thumbConn.connect();
        InputStream thumbIn = thumbConn.getInputStream(); 
        BufferedInputStream thumbBuff = new BufferedInputStream(thumbIn);
        itemImage .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(thumbBuff));
        System.out.println("do you see the picture?");
        thumbBuff.close(); 
        thumbIn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

I donot get any error, the app get the image from the server, but I do not see it, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

you cannot perform UI task in `doInBackground`. Set image to image view in `postExecute()`.

```
itemImage .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(thumbBuff));
```

put this line in `postExecute().`

Comment: Hi, thanks  I changed my code as you said: http://pastebin.com/TRFedXAz, but still no success

Answer (score 2):

UI updatetion part should be done on UiThread only. so just put

```
itemImage .setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

on your `onPostExecute()` method. you have to  return Bitmap from `doInBackground` .

Answer (score 0):

One can also use onProgressUpdate() call back API to update UI inside from doinBackground().

Use publishProgress() to initiate the call back onProgressUpdate()